# canvas.drawImage .toDataURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So far i have this code for add a little watermark to a image and drawimage it to a canvas, now i'm trying to get that canvas data to DataURL, for some reason it's not working as it supposed to be

could anyone give me a idea why ? and maybe how to fix it and get URI data of it

here's my code

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var watermark = new Image();
watermark.src = "http://dummyimage.com/80x80/red/ffffff";

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/500x700/303030/ffffff";

context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
context.drawImage(watermark,0,0,50,50);
```

HTML

```
<canvas width="500" height="700" id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

tried with `context.toDataURL('image/png');`, but it doesn't return

[Here's a link to my bin](http://jsbin.com/lisogokahu/edit?html,js)

Answer (score 0):

`toDataURL` method exists on the canvas and not the context.

The next error that you'll get after fixing that is:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

The image must exist on the same domain to fix that.

You may also have to preload the images.

Comment: preloading and cors wouldn't be a issue, i'm building a phonegap app with camera function, one image from camera and watermark from inside app dir, i'll look around to fix toDataUrl thing, any directions ?

Comment: i've managed to get it working, now it's returning a blank image for URI, i'm guessing that's because i'm not preloading it, http://jsbin.com/wiyoqerota, i'll try with phonegap





'**Edit**'

nope, it returns white in phonegap too, any idea why is it ? :/